# Laravel 5 - inserting old data into form via variable

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have a slight problem.  I have a system whereby I can drag and drop my own forms.  The html code for a form is saved in my database.  When it comes to the edit page, I do something like the following

```
{!! Form::model($project->document, [
    'class'=>'form-horizontal',
    'method' => 'PATCH',
    'route' => ['projects.documents.update', $project, $document->id]
]) !!}


{!! $documentData->documentData !!}

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::submit('Save Data', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
</div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

`$documentData->documentData` contains the html code for this particular form.

Now my problem is, `$documentData->form_data` contains the old inputs for this form.

Is there any way to get this old input into the form, the way I am currently handling things?

Thanks

Comment: One way that I just thought is save the old input to the database and then you can retrieve them

Comment: The old input is in the database already, but it is in a different variable to the form html code.

Comment: you can get the content from the database and save it to the right name of variable ;) then you can load that variable with your form ;)

Comment: Is the form in `$documentData->documentData` pure HTML?

Comment: yes, it is pure html code

Answer (score 0):

in controller you can access old input by $request->flash(); while in frontend you can access old by `input type="text" name="name" value="{{ $name }}"`